# hibernate many-to-many association with extra columns in join table example

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have 3 tables as @Entity, and 2 join tables in my spring + hibernate app.
In one of join table i have extra column. I want to take info from this info column when i take info from my main table.
Main table code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class Items {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "crafts"
        ,joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
        ,inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "plot_id"))
private Set<Plots> plotInfo = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "item_materials"
        ,joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
        ,inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "material_id"))
private Set<Materials> materialsInfo = new HashSet<>();
```

Table item_materials have this columns "id, item_id(fkey), material_id(fkey), expense" and one of this which names as "expense" i need to have in my final result.
How can i code my class to have "expense" in my result?

I read about @embeddable but still dont understand how to use in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `@ManyToMany` association. Map the join table as entity and model it similar to this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class Items {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item")
  private Set<Crafts> plotInfo = new HashSet<>();
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "plots")
public class Plots {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "plot")
  private Set<Crafts> items = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "crafts")
public class Crafts {
  @EmbeddedId
  private CraftsId id;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "item_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Items item;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "plot_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Plots plot;
}

@Embeddable
public class CraftsId {
  @Column(name = "item_id")
  private Integer itemId;
  @Column(name = "plot_id")
  private Integer plotId;
  // equals + hashCode
}
```